# “Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found”

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting “Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found”. I have updated the gradle distribution version in gradle wrapper properties but to no avail. Do I need to write the build gradle dependencies somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add in your top level file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    } 
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: what and where is this "top level file"?

Comment: @noypee the top-level file is the build.gradle file that you can find in the root of the project.